# htmltab can't find the table using numeric or character vector as 'which' argument

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-table

I am trying to use htmltab to scrape some tables from the Federal Reserve website to RStudio.

This code works for one table using a numeric vector of 1 for the tables' rank 'which' argument:

```
url <- 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/h6/current/default.htm'
df1 <- htmltab(url,1)
```

However another table doesn't seem to accept numeric vectors for the 'which' argument.

```
url <- 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/bst_recenttrends_accessible.htm'
df2 <- htmltab(url,1)
```

## Output:

> Error: Couldn't find the table. Try passing (a different) information to the which argument.

The RDocumentation for [htmltab](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/htmltab/versions/0.7.1/topics/htmltab) mentions using a character vector that describes an XPath for the table as the 'which' argument, but I can't seem to get this to work either:

```
url <- 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/bst_recenttrends_accessible.htm'
xp <- '//*[@id="bstContainer"]/table[1]'
df2 <- htmltab(url, xp)
```

## Output:

> Error in Node[[1](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/htmltab/versions/0.7.1/topics/htmltab)] : subscript out of bounds

Can anyone see where I am going wrong pulling in this table?

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but can say something about the reason the second url is not working. The data in the second url is not stored in an html table, but is generated by javascript code. That is why htmltab does not find any tables. You may want to look into packages such as RSelenium to do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code isn't working is that you can only scrape static html with your method. The second page loads data into its table dynamically, so the table doesn't actually exist in the page you are downloading to R. Fortunately, it is straightforward to get the data by following the link to the underlying xml used by the xhr request. It is also straightforward to read this into a data frame.

```r
require("xml2")
page <- read_html("https://www.federalreserve.gov/data.xml")
tables <- xml_find_all(page,"//series")
first_table <- data.frame(date = xml_attr(xml_contents(tables[[1]]), "index"),
                          amount = xml_attr(xml_contents(tables[[1]]), "value"))

# > first_table
# >          date     amount
# > 1    1-Aug-07  870261.00
# > 2    8-Aug-07  865453.00
# > 3   15-Aug-07  864931.00
# > 4   22-Aug-07  862775.00
# > 5   29-Aug-07  872873.00
# > 6    5-Sep-07  871156.00
# > 7   12-Sep-07  886314.00
# > 8   19-Sep-07  867732.00
# > 9   26-Sep-07  889900.00
# > 10   3-Oct-07  869051.00
#...
```